# Convert Resultant Values to List of Strings in Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm having issues with returning a list of strings of the `.Value` of a Linq query:

```
    Dim details = <Details>
                      <Vector size="5">
                          <Item>Syntactic Structures</Item>
                          <Item>Introduction</Item>
                          <Item>The Independence of Grammar</Item>
                          <Item>An Elementary Linguistic Theory</Item>
                          <Item>Phrase Structure</Item>
                      </Vector>
                  </Details>
    Dim chapterTitles = details.<Vector>.<Item>.Skip(1).Take(4)
```

Is correct in that it returns the list of XElements I want (items 1 - 4, base 0), but I really just need a list of strings for the `.Value` of those XElements. Maybe I'm just dense here, but anything I've tried in the `chapterTitles` query isn't working (appending with .ToList.ToString, etc.). `details.<Vector>.<Item>.Skip(1).Take(4).Value` just returns the first XElement's value.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do a `Select` to transform the results from `XElement`s to `string`s.

```
Dim chapterTitles = details.<Vector>.<Item>.Skip(1).Take(4).Select(Function(item) item.Value)
```

or

```
Dim chapterTitles = From item In details.<Vector>.<Item>.Skip(1).Take(4) _
                    Select item.Value
```

Comment: Ugh, how could I be so dense! Works like a charm, thank you! Needs 10 more minues to accept, so I'll do it then.